# Should I use .getContentText() in this Google Script GET request?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, get, icalendar, urlfetch

Both of these appear to return and log the same thing. Does it matter which is  used? The first example is what's shown on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

```
var rawCalendar1 =  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/blog/events.ics");   
Logger.log(rawCalendar1.getContentText());


var rawCalendar2 =  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/blog/events.ics");
Logger.log(rawCalendar2);
```

Comment: @AntonDementiev that is correct, why aren't you posting that as an answer???

Comment: Sorry, I reposted this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type for UrlFetchApp.fetch() is HttpResponse. In your example, you can call several methods on rawCalendar1 to inspect the returned value.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response

getContentText() converts the contents of HttpResponse to type 'string'. Likewise, Logger.log() casts what is between the brackets to 'string', which is essentially the same as calling getContentText() on it.